# Sprite.position.x/y in pySFML read-only?

Tags: python, sprite, sfml

I can't move a sprite, changes to `Sprite.position.x/y` are ignored. I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug in pySFML?

```
In [1]: import sfml

In [2]: texture = sfml.Texture.from_file('fire.png')

In [3]: sprite = sfml.Sprite(texture)

In [4]: sprite.position
Out[4]: sf.Vector2(0.0x, 0.0y)

In [5]: sprite.position.x = 300  # Doesn't work?

In [6]: sprite.position
Out[6]: sf.Vector2(0.0x, 0.0y)
```

I'm using Python 3.3, SFML 2.0 and pySFML 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned in [other forum](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=13448.0), it's limitation of pySFML (or SFML). Shortest workaround would be this:

```
sprite.position = 300, sprite.position.y
```